# Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'

Tags: android, flutter

[image]

[image]

Error when I try to run flutter project inside VS code.

Answer (score 1):

Try opening the android folder with android studio, and try building the app from there. It should tell you why it is failing.